# Pandas dropping all the columns that contain any nan except one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to drop all columns that include any nan, except one particular column.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.nan,4],[1,2,4,5],[np.nan,6,np.nan,6],[4,np.nan,6,7],[1,2,3,4]], columns=['A','B','C','D'])

>>> df
     A    B    C  D
0  1.0  2.0  NaN  4
1  1.0  2.0  4.0  5
2  NaN  6.0  NaN  6
3  4.0  NaN  6.0  7
4  1.0  2.0  3.0  4
```

I like to drop all containing nan except df['C'].

```
>>> df
     C  D
0  NaN  4
1  4.0  5
2  NaN  6
3  6.0  7
4  3.0  4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC, use [`isna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) + [`any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to check which columns to drop

```
d = df.isna().any()
```

Set the columns you want to ignore to `False`

```
cols_to_ignore = ['C']
d[cols_to_ignore] = False
```

And just `loc`

```
df.loc[:, ~d]

    C   D
0   NaN 4
1   4.0 5
2   NaN 6
3   6.0 7
4   3.0 4
```

Comment: I assume in the text you meant "...which columns to drop" instead of rows

Comment: "d" is a Series containing the names of the null columns of which each is set to a value of True.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of keeping columns, you can drop them all, and then add the one you want back on.

```
newdf = df.dropna(axis=1).copy() #.copy() is only here to suppress a warning.
newdf['C'] = df['C']
newdf
#produces this dataframe:
   D    C
0  4  NaN
1  5  4.0
2  6  NaN
3  7  6.0
4  4  3.0
```

Comment: This changes the columns' order.

Answer (score 2):

I would also use `isna().any()`, but also use `df.columns.difference(['columns_to_ignore'])`:

```
tmp = df[df.columns.difference(['C'])].isna().any()

df.drop(tmp.index[tmp], axis=1)

     C  D
0  NaN  4
1  4.0  5
2  NaN  6
3  6.0  7
4  3.0  4
```

**Explanation**:

`tmp` is a dataframe of booleans *excluding* your columns to ignore:

```
>>> tmp
A     True
B     True
D    False
dtype: bool
```

so `tmp.index[tmp]` returns a list of the columns to drop:

```
>>> tmp.index[tmp]
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `combine_first`

```
df.dropna(1).combine_first(df[['C']])
Out[301]: 
     C  D
0  NaN  4
1  4.0  5
2  NaN  6
3  6.0  7
4  3.0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner using `subset` parameter from pandas `dropna`.

```
df.dropna(subset=[n for n in df if n != 'column_to_keep'], inplace=True)
```

> `column_to_keep` is the column where you want nan to be preserved.